# toon material from blender internal rendered in cycles render engine?

Tags: rendering, render-layers

Is it possible the toon material and specular from the blender internal render engine to be rendered in the cycles render engine by using render layers?

Comment: Or, is it possible to render a cartoon scene with diffuse and glossy, but the glossy to be the toon specular material from the blender internal render engine?

Comment: Do you mean you have a Cycles scene, but you only want that one object to be toon-shaded, or you want a node setup on how to use the Cycles toon shader?

Comment: I mean, Is it possible materials from blender internal to be rendered in cycles?

Comment: You can sort of re-create materials in Cycles, but they won't look exactly the same because Cycles is a more advanced rendering engine. If you want the objects that you made in Blender Internal to be rendered on a Cycles scene, use the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender internal and cycles are completely separate rendering engines, only the object surface data can be shared between them. Each render engine uses incompatible material data.

To combine the two render engines you can render an image from each engine and composite the two results together. You can either do this manually by saving one or both of the results to file and inputting the files in the compositor or 2d graphics application. Or you can have two scenes, one using blender internal and one using cycles that can both be input into the compositor.

[image]

BlenderCookie [has a tutorial](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/10/10/compositing-smoke-simulations-cycles-renders/) explaining this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks. About the link -  Is that the same as if the smoke simulation was available in cycles, as it is in the internal?

Comment: Because, the internal has no light bouncing, so is it possible that by using this approach the smoke has now light bouncing?

Comment: I mean, Is the smoke just visible in the scene as it is in the internal or is the smoke now rendered in cycles?

Comment: The tutorial was before cycles could render smoke, so you rendered the smoke with internal and the rest in cycles then composite together.